# OpenCL - change buffer flags

Tags: opencl

Is there a way to change the flags of a opencl buffer once allocated?

My use case is the following:

1) create data on device
2) do large amounts of work on device with said data

I want to mark the data as CL_MEM_READ_ONLY to enable possible optimisations during 2, but of course it can't be read-only when it's being created in 1.

It would be acceptable to copy the data to a new read-only buffer, but I can't see any way of doing that without going via host memory.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the the other answers, I also believe there not likely to be any significant performance gains to be had from using `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY`, as opposed to simply marking the buffer as `const` (or putting it in the `constant` address space, if small enough) inside your kernel.

However, you *can* achieve this using sub-buffers. If you create your buffer with `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`, you can then create a sub-buffer that has the `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` flag set.

```
cl_mem buffer    = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size, NULL, &err);

cl_buffer_region = {0, size};
cl_mem robuffer  = clCreateSubBuffer(buffer, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                     CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION,
                                     (const void*)&region, &err);
```

Comment: Marking the buffer as constant should be enough to give you all possible optimizations. The reason for this is that the compiler doesn't know or care about what flags are set on the memory buffer when generating code. If you pass in a read_only buffer to a kernel that writes to it, the kernel will try to write and only the MMU or another protection can stop it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mutate the flags of an existing buffer.  However, *I think* you can create two buffers that wrap the same host memory.  If you are on an integrated graphics platform like Intel or AMD and use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, you can create a read-write buffer that wraps a piece of host memory.  (The usual constraints apply: has to be page-aligned and even cacheline length on Intel, not sure about AMD's).  You can create a second buffer wrapping the same region with different options (read only) and use it separately.

It's definitely illegal to use overlapped regions in different enqueues at the same time.

> The result of OpenCL commands that operate on multiple buffer objects created with the same host_ptr or overlapping host regions is considered to be undefined.

(from [CreateBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)) But barring that, it should work.

However, in the end, I strongly suspect you won't really gain anything.  Implementations are free to ignore these flags.  And I suspect that the overlap case above will force the implementation to ignore them (set the page access to the least restrictive combination of buffers mapping it).  Integrated GPUs almost certainly will ignore those flags (I think Intel does).

What sort of optimizations were you hoping for?

Comment: I am targeting HPC gear mainly, so it's going to be totally separate GPUs.

I can see that your solution can work for host memory, but it seems like a very nasty hack to do something very simple. Also, the aliased regions will probably lose the optimiser any guarantees it had (although the undefined behaviour in the spec suggests maybe not)

I can accept that you can't change the flags on an existing buffer, but surely there is a way to initialise a CL_MEM_READ_ONLY buffer from device memory without going via the host?

Comment: There is no way to do it from the device. CL_MEM_READ_ONLY specify that the data is meant to be read *exclusively*, which, for example, could enable an implementation to place the data on a specific read-only memory in the device.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that it should depend on how you allocate the buffer initially. For some flags, you may reuse (you can try with alloc_host). Some may not allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the flags of a opencl buffer once allocated?

No, it is not. You will have to create another buffer and call a copybuffer from one to another.

---

However I really doubt of the need of this. The memory flags affect (mainly) how the sync operation between host and device is performed. But when the memory is in the device, I doubt any optimizations can be done at all. (unless the memory consist of just some KB of data).

Even if optimizations are possible, the compiler should be clever enough to do it as well if the memory is declared in the kernel as `constant` or `read_only`. Regardless of the flags set to the memory buffer.

Comment: Is it legal to call clEnqueueCopyBuffer with a destination buffer that has CL_MEM_READ_ONLY set?